# change email Content headers when using Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, email-headers

I successfully sent email using Gmail API. I noticed that the text is put to new line every 66-69 characters. This way the text, fills only half of screen. Any idea how to set it to fill entire space available?

To send emails, I use this github project: https://github.com/chris-brown-nz/python-gmail-api

Headers regarding content are:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I have a feeling that I need to change Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding headers in order to make text fill entire space available. Any idea how to do this?

EDIT: I added this code,

```
message = MIMEText(message_body, 'html')
```

to the __create_message function and now the text isnt put to new line every 68 characters. But this caused new issue. Now API ignores any new line argument set intentionally by me.

EDIT: adding `<br>` works for HTML based emails. What about plain text emails?

Perhaps a better question is, how to add option to display as html and plain text?

Comment: Have you tried html line breaks now that you have `Content-Type: text/html;`? I.e. `<br/>`.

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. However, I heard horror stories about Deliverability of HTML based emails. Any way to do it with plain text instead?

Comment: You might want to look into sending a [**multipart mail with a html part and a plain text part**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5). The plain text version can only have 68 characters per line, sadly, but this way users on older clients that can't handle html will still be able to see something.